# Android Logger setting FileName

Tags: android, logging

How can I change the log filename in android?

I have an application, which starts with a text-box to allow users to enter their id. Once this is done, I want that all the logs happening(say even system logs) should goto this file, unless some other user starts the application and enters a new id.

Any idea how this could be done?

R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/microlog4android/

Comment: i was hoping that there should be some better way, but this works too.

Comment: If you think that Microlog4Android is not up-to-date, please contribute to it! ;-)